# Proper way of implementing a periodic action

Tags: java, android, service, scheduled-tasks, task

I have the need to send and take something from a server in Android on every 10 seconds. Here, on StackOverflow, and in the documentation I found literally dozens of ways to implement it (and everything I tried does the job), but it seems that everywhere someone says something is wrong with that way.

I tried with a looping `AsyncTask` until it is canceled (that is untill the activity is killed), and I found out that it's not a good solution. Before that I tried with regular `Threads`, then I found out that it drains the battery a lot.

Now I've done it with a `Runnable` and and the ScheduledExecutorService's `scheduleAtFixedRate` function, similar to the code proposed here:
[How to run an async task for every x mins in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207362/how-to-run-an-async-task-afor-every-x-mins-in-android) . Needless to say, it works. But will it work if my Activity is in the background, for example the user is answering an incoming call?

In the end, I don't know anymore what is the most proper way of doing it on an Android phone.

Tnx in advance.

Comment: Anything periodic with that period will kill the battery as it will never let the CPU ( and the system ) to sleep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Handler` it has various methods like `postDelayed(Runnable r, long delayMillis),postAtTime(Runnable r, Object token, long uptimeMillis)` etc.

```
Handler mHandler =  new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

      //Start runnable here.
    }
   };

mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, delayMillis)
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but if the transfer lasts a bit longer it lags the UI.

Comment: In your handleMessage() you could use a Thread (sending another message to the Handler on completion, in which the UI can be updated) or an AsyncTask to run the task in the background.

Comment: Try invoking Asynctask inside handleMessage(). It will not lag the GUI then.

Comment: Thankyou, this will probably be the way to go :) .

Answer (score 1):

Would recommend using the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and [BroadcastReceivers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) if you need your scheduled task to occur even when your app is not currently running.

Otherwise the documentation recommends using [Handlers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

As discussed in the comments of AmitD's question. If the task needs to run in the background, you can use an AsyncTask inside the handler callback to achieve this.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler() {
  public void handlerMessage(Message msg) {
    new AsyncTask<TaskParameterType,Integer,TaskResultType>() {
      protected TaskResultType doInBackground(TaskParameterType... taskParameters) {
        // Perform background task - runs asynchronously
      }
      protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        // update the UI with progress (in response to call to publishProgress())
        // - runs on UI thread
      }
      protected void onPostExecute(TaskResultType result) {
        // update the UI with completion - runs on UI thread
      }
    }.execute(taskParameterObject);
  }
};
handler.postMessageDelayed(msg, delayMillis);
```

For repeated executions the doc also mentions [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) as an option (which is preferred over [java.util.Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html), primarily due to extra flexibility, it seems).

```
final Handler handler = new Handler() {
  public void handlerMessage(Message msg) {
    // update the UI - runs on the UI thread
  }
};
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor exec = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
ScheduledFuture f = exec.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      // perform background task - runs on a background thread
      handler.sendMessage(msg); // trigger UI update
    }
  }, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 1):

Implementing repeating tasks is largely a function of the enormity/processing of the task. Will the UI block on your task. If so, then you can AsyncTask with a Handler and TimerTask.

In your activity onCreate or any generic function :

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    timer = new Timer();
        doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                try {
                 // Instantiate the AsyncTask here and call the execute method

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

          }
        });
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask,0,UPDATE_FREQUENCY)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I would use the `Timer` class with a `TimerTask`: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html