# Android AsyncTask vs Looper Handler

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, handler, looper

I have implemented a background service that queries the database every 5 seconds. If the query returns no results, the service should wait for 5 seconds and query database again. If the query returns results, it should call an activity and pass the results to it.

I started with an AsyncTask which basically reads the database in the doInBackground() and returns the results, so that the onPostExecute() calls the activity. Right now I am calling the AsyncTask.execute() in the onStartCommand() of the service. But that means the task gets called only once when the service starts.

Should I instead use a Looper/Handler for my task, something similar to as explained here :
[How to run an async task for every x mins in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207362/how-to-run-an-async-task-for-every-x-mins-in-android)

But if I understood that code correctly, the service will need to call the startRepeatingTask in a loop somewhere, but I was hoping the doSomething() itself could get called every x mins.

I am new to Android, sorry if the question is pretty basic or maybe I just didn't understand the other solution and was hoping someone could explain if that could work for my situation!

Thanks!

Comment: That is not the case that you think.  The code for startRepeatingTask actually calls the handler again at the end of the run().  So every INTERVAL, it will fire the Runnable again and hence the doSomething() once more.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! But then doesn't some function have to call startRepeatingTask()? I guess I could put startRepeatingTask() in an infinite loop? Would that work?

Comment: You don't need startRepeatingTask( ) in a loop for it to work infinitely.  That's what I was trying to get across.  startRepeatingTask( ) calls itself recursively from within the Runnable.  You just need to call startRepeatingTask( ) once. And that is why the original author adds a removeCallbacks( ) function to be sure to stop it later.

Comment: Ok, understood this time! Thanks again for your comment!

Comment: KMN  Have you given any thought to battery consumption?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! That is a concern, yes, but not a priority at the moment. I am planning to change the code later in a way that the database reads don't need to occur as frequent as 5 seconds.