# The right way to connect to MySQL every second

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want to check my MySQL database every second and get the data from it

This is what I tried I made the connection in a separate thread and make it sleep

Thread:

```
class Updater extends Thread {
ArrayList<chatData> list = new ArrayList<chatData>();
Boolean thereIsNewData = false;
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
String yourID = prefs.getString("KEY_USERNAME", "No login info available");



void getData(){
    chatServiceHandler jsonParser = new chatServiceHandler();

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nvp = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("yourID", yourID));

    String json = jsonParser.makeServiceCall("http://example.com/getMSG.php", contactsServiceHandler.GET, nvp);

    Log.d("Response: ", "> " + json);

    if (json != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
            if (jsonObj != null) {
                list.clear();
                JSONArray contactsArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("MSGhandling");

                for (int i = 0; i < contactsArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject catObj = (JSONObject) contactsArray.get(i);
                    chatData cat = new chatData(catObj.getString("sender"), catObj.getString("receiver"),catObj.getString("msg"),catObj.getString("msgID"));
                    list.add(cat);
                    thereIsNewData = true;
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            thereIsNewData = false;
        }

    } else {
        Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
        thereIsNewData = false;
    }
}




@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            DatabaseAdapter helper = new DatabaseAdapter(UpdaterService.this);
            getData();

            if(thereIsNewData){
                for(int i =0; i < list.size(); i++){
                    chatData messages = list.get(i);
                    Log.d(TAG, "From: "+messages.getSenderID()+" TO:"+messages.getReceiverID()+" MSG: "+messages.getMSG());
                    helper.storeMSG(messages.getSenderID() , messages.getReceiverID() , messages.getMSG() , messages.getMsgID());
                    Intent newMessage = new Intent();
                    newMessage.setAction("NEW_MESSAGE");
                    sendBroadcast(newMessage);
                }
                list.clear();
                thereIsNewData = false;
            }else{

                Log.d(TAG, "There is no new data");
            }

            sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
   }
```

}

It does it work but stops after a few seconds for half a minute and shows an error than back to do the same thing again:

-----------------------------------**EDIT**--------------------------------

**LOG_CAT:**

```
`190-318/system_process E/ThrottleService﹕ problem during onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) 03
04-02 10:37:44.162      389-403/com.android.systemui E/JavaBinder﹕ *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
    java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadObjectException
            at android.os.Parcel.writeException(Parcel.java:1326)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:370)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException
            at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
                at     android.content.IIntentReceiver$Stub$Proxy.performReceive(IIntentReceiver.java:121) at android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread.scheduleRegisteredReceiver(ActivityThread.java:771)  at android.app.ApplicationThreadNative.onTransact(ApplicationThreadNative.java:381)
                at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

04-02 10:41:00.282      630-644/com.khaled.zg W/System.err﹕  org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://example.com refused
04-02 10:41:00.292      630-644/com.khaled.zg W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
04-02 10:41:00.292      630-644/com.khaled.zg W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
04-02 10:41:00.292      630-644/com.khaled.zg W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
04-02 10:41:00.306      630-644/com.khaled.zg W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
04-02 10:41:00.306      630-644/com.khaled.zg W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
04-02 10:41:00.306      630-644/com.khaled.zg W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
04-02 10:41:00.306      630-644/com.khaled.zg W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
04-02 10:41:00.313      630-644/com.khaled.zg W/System.err﹕ at com.khaled.zg.contactsServiceHandler.makeServiceCall(contactsServiceHandler.java:79)
04-02 10:41:00.326      630-644/com.khaled.zg W/System.err﹕ at com.khaled.zg.UpdaterService$Updater.getContacts(UpdaterService.java:101)
04-02 10:41:00.326      630-644/com.khaled.zg W/System.err﹕ at com.khaled.zg.UpdaterService$Updater.run(UpdaterService.java:135)
04-02 10:41:00.333      630-644/com.khaled.zg W/System.err﹕ Caused by:     java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /185.27.134.163 (port 80): connect failed:     ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
04-02 10:41:00.345      630-644/com.khaled.zg W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
04-02 10:41:00.345      630-644/com.khaled.zg W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
04-02 10:41:00.345      630-644/com.khaled.zg W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
04-02 10:41:00.353      630-644/com.khaled.zg W/System.err﹕ at     java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
04-02 10:41:00.353      630-644/com.khaled.zg W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
04-02 10:41:00.364      630-644/com.khaled.zg W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
04-02 10:41:00.364      630-644/com.khaled.zg W/System.err﹕ ... 9 more
04-02 10:41:00.364      630-644/com.khaled.zg W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
04-02 10:41:00.383      630-644/com.khaled.zg W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
04-02 10:41:00.383      630-644/com.khaled.zg W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
04-02 10:41:00.393      630-644/com.khaled.zg W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
04-02 10:41:00.393      630-644/com.khaled.zg W/System.err﹕ at     libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)`
```

Am I doing it wrong? is there any other way or a solution to my problem?

Or does the host is what causes the problem?

Comment: do you debug the code? find from where you are getting this error

Comment: @Sreekanthss I edit with new error... please check it out

Comment: i think your thread  was stopping some where, check that, why you dot use async  task to download data

Comment: @Sreekanthss How can I know that?, I've read that AsyncTask should be used only once and I can not execute it every second

Comment: You can use handler if you want to initiate something every X seconds,http://stackoverflow.com/a/6207519