# Android App Skips Frames, crashes after a while

Tags: java, android, multithreading, background-process, ui-thread

I have posted before about my app skipping frames, because I may not be doing the background activities and updating the UI correctly, here's a link to the question:
[Doing background stuff on a different UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734133/doing-background-stuff-on-a-different-ui/34734261?noredirect=1#comment57250958_34734261)

I have used AsyncTask, Handlers, Timers, Threads...I still get the same error that the app is skipping frames.

Here are my full codes:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String DEBUG_TAG = "MainActvity";
    public int mInterval = 5000; // 10 seconds by default, can be changed here, it should be aligned
                                 // with how many secs in takes to get latency packets
    private NetworkInformation dsNetwork;

    private TextView wifiTextView;
    private TextView ipTextView;
    private TextView macTextView;
    private TextView ssidTextView;
    private TextView linkSpeedTextView;
    private TextView frequencyTextView;
    private TextView signalLevelTextView;
    private TextView dlBandwidthTextView;
    private TextView upBandwidthTextView;
    private TextView latencyTextView;

    private Handler handler;
    //private Runnable runnableCode;
    //private Timer timerAsync;
    //private TimerTask timerTaskAsync;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        wifiTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.wifi_textView);
        ipTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ip_val_textView);
        macTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mac_val_textView);
        ssidTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ssid_val_textView);
        linkSpeedTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.linkSpeed_val_textView);
        frequencyTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.frequency_val_textView);
        signalLevelTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.signalLevel_val_textView);
        dlBandwidthTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dlBandwidth_val_textView);
        upBandwidthTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.upBandwidth_val_textView);
        latencyTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.latency_val_textView);

        handler = new Handler();
        startRepeatingTask();
    }


    Runnable mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            updateUI(dsNetwork); //this function can change value of mInterval.
            handler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker, mInterval);
        }
    };

    void startRepeatingTask() {
        dsNetwork = new NetworkInformation(getApplicationContext());
        mStatusChecker.run();
    }

    void stopRepeatingTask() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(mStatusChecker);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    private void updateUI(NetworkInformation dsNetwork){
        // Handles updating the textviews in the UI
        //Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "updateUI(NetworkInformation)");

        if (dsNetwork.isConnected()){
            wifiTextView.setText(R.string.wifi_is_on);
            wifiTextView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

            ipTextView.setText(dsNetwork.getIpAddress());
            macTextView.setText(dsNetwork.getMacAddress());
            ssidTextView.setText(dsNetwork.getSsid());
            linkSpeedTextView.setText(String.valueOf(dsNetwork.getLinkSpeed()) + " Mbps");
            frequencyTextView.setText(String.valueOf(dsNetwork.getFrequency()) + " MHz");
            signalLevelTextView.setText(String.valueOf(dsNetwork.getSignalLevel()) + "%");
            dlBandwidthTextView.setText(String.valueOf(dsNetwork.getDlBandwidth()/1000) + " Mbps");
            upBandwidthTextView.setText(String.valueOf(dsNetwork.getDlBandwidth()/1000) + " Mbps");
            latencyTextView.setText(String.valueOf(dsNetwork.getLatency("10.10.0.62")) + " ms");
        }
        else {
            wifiTextView.setText(R.string.wifi_is_off);
            wifiTextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);

            ipTextView.setText("N/A");
            macTextView.setText("N/A");
            ssidTextView.setText("N/A");
            linkSpeedTextView.setText("N/A");
            frequencyTextView.setText("N/A");
            signalLevelTextView.setText("N/A");
            dlBandwidthTextView.setText("N/A");
            upBandwidthTextView.setText("N/A");
            latencyTextView.setText("N/A");
        }

    }

}
```

And here is the the network class that handles getting the information:

```
public class NetworkInformation {


    public static int SIGNAL_LEVEL_LIMIT = 101;
    public Context mContext;
    public static String DEBUG_TAG = "NetworkInformation";


    private boolean isConnected;
    private String networkType; //Wifi, Mobile Data, Ethernet...
    private String ssid;
    private String ipAddress;
    private String macAddress;
    private int frequency;      // in MHz
    private int linkSpeed;      // in Mbps
    private int signalLevel;    // Measured from 1 to SIGNAL_LEVEL_LIMIT
    private int dlBandwidth;    // downstream bandwidth in Kbps
    private int upBandwidth;    // upstream bandwidth in Kbps


    public boolean isConnected() {
        return isConnected;
    }

    public String getNetworkType() {
        return networkType;
    }

    public String getSsid() {
        return ssid;
    }

    public int getFrequency() {
        return frequency;
    }

    public String getIpAddress() {
        return ipAddress;
    }

    public String getMacAddress() {
        return macAddress;
    }

    public int getLinkSpeed() {
        return linkSpeed;
    }

    public int getSignalLevel() {
        return signalLevel;
    }

    public int getDlBandwidth() {
        return dlBandwidth;
    }

    public int getUpBandwidth() {
        return upBandwidth;
    }




    // Constructor: gets application contex, sets whether or not there is connection, and sets the
    // connection-related variables
    public NetworkInformation(Context mContext) {

        this.mContext = mContext;
        setConnectionStatus();
        setNetworkType();

        if (this.networkType == "None") {
            // TODO: handle the case when there's no connection
        }
        if (this.networkType == "Wifi") {
            setWifiInfo();
        }
        if(this.networkType == "Mobile Data") {
            //TODO: setMobileDataInfo()
        }
    }



    /*
    Returns the latency to a given server in mili-seconds by issuing a ping command.
    system will issue 5 ICMP Echo Request packet each having size of 56 bytes
    every second, and returns the avg latency of them.
    Returns 0 when there is no connection
     */
    public double getLatency(String ipAddress){
        String pingCommand = "/system/bin/ping -c 4 " + ipAddress;
        String inputLine = "";
        double avgRtt = 0;

        try {
            // execute the command on the environment interface
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(pingCommand);
            // gets the input stream to get the output of the executed command
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
            while ((inputLine != null)) {
                if (inputLine.length() > 0 && inputLine.contains("avg")) {  // when we get to the last line of executed ping command
                    break;
                }
                inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "getLatency: EXCEPTION");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Extracting the average round trip time from the inputLine string
        String afterEqual = inputLine.substring(inputLine.indexOf("="), inputLine.length()).trim();
        String afterFirstSlash = afterEqual.substring(afterEqual.indexOf('/') + 1, afterEqual.length()).trim();
        String strAvgRtt = afterFirstSlash.substring(0, afterFirstSlash.indexOf('/'));
        avgRtt = Double.valueOf(strAvgRtt);

        return avgRtt;
    }






    /*
    The following are private utility functions
     */


    // Checks if the device is connected to the Internet, and sets the class variables
    private void setConnectionStatus() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        // if there is internet connection, set the variabel
        if ((activeNetwork != null) && (activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting()))
            this.isConnected = true;
        else
            this.isConnected = false;
    }



    // Returns the type of network: Internet, Mobile Data, WiMax...
    private void setNetworkType() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        String networkType = "None";

        switch (activeNetwork.getType()) {
            case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI:
                networkType = "Wifi";
                break;
            case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE:
                networkType = "Mobile Data";
                break;
            case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET:
                networkType = "Ethernet";
                break;
            case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIMAX:
                networkType = "WiMAX";
                break;
            case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_VPN:
                networkType = "VPN";
                break;
        }

        this.networkType = networkType;
    }



    // Gets the wifi information, and updates the class variables
    private void setWifiInfo() {

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        Network[] network = cm.getAllNetworks();
        NetworkCapabilities netCapab = cm.getNetworkCapabilities(network[0]);

        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();

        if (wifiInfo != null) {
            this.ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
            this.ipAddress = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wifiInfo.getIpAddress());
            this.macAddress = wifiInfo.getMacAddress();
            this.linkSpeed = wifiInfo.getLinkSpeed();
            this.frequency = wifiInfo.getFrequency();
            this.dlBandwidth = netCapab.getLinkDownstreamBandwidthKbps();
            this.upBandwidth = netCapab.getLinkUpstreamBandwidthKbps();
            this.signalLevel = wifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getRssi(), SIGNAL_LEVEL_LIMIT);
        }
    }
}
```

When the app runs at first, it's doing fine, but it gets slower and slower and finally crashes after 10 minutes or so...
I keep getting this error in logcat, it keeps coming:
I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 183 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Oh, and I did the Handler in this way: [Repeat a task with a time delay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242268/repeat-a-task-with-a-time-delay/6242292#6242292)
and also this way:
[Update TextView Every Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814714/update-textview-every-second?lq=1)

But none worked. Someone save me please...

Comment: I used this one too, using schedulethreadexecuter, still the same error
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098806/where-do-i-create-and-use-scheduledthreadpoolexecutor-timertask-or-handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `getLatency(...)` is a long running operation (you start external process and do some I/O). This kind of stuff should not be called in main thread, where you are updating UI. Choreographer tries to maintain 60fps, so 3 seconds of blocked main thread can result in 180 dropped frames.

Start some background task, obtain **all** the data you need, and then update UI in main thread.

Comment: That might be it, I commented it out in updateUI method, and now it works...
Where/how do you recommend I use getLatency method? Should I separately call it with dsNetwork = new NetworkInformation(getApplicationContext()); ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Move the logic from NetworkInfo class (it should be just a datastructure) to another one . Call those methods in background, and set returned values to NetworkInfo object fields. Pass NI object to the main thread.