# how to call a function every 5 minutes?

Tags: java, android

I need to call the speak method every 5 minutes, then i want to run in background the async method called callspeak, that calls back the speak method(a public method of a different class). It has to loop every 5 minutes

```
    class callSpeak extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    activityAudio a = new activityAudio();
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        try
        {
         while (true){
               a.speak();
                Thread.sleep(300000);
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {e.getMessage();}
      return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: In this case I would use a Handler calling a postDelayed function with your desired interval on it, check this thread, you can find a good code example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207362/how-to-run-an-async-task-for-every-x-mins-in-android

Answer (score 6):

If you want to run the method only when the app is open, you can simply use [TimerTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html).

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer ();
TimerTask myTask = new TimerTask () {
    @Override
    public void run () {
        // your code 
        callSpeak().execute() // Your method
    }
};

myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(myTask , 0l, 5 * (60*1000)); // Runs every 5 mins
```

If you want to run it in background even if app is not running, you can use [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) and repeat the task every 5 mins.

Hope it helps

Comment: You can follow this codelab - https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-alarm-manager/index.html . May I know why you want to run it in background?

Comment: I solved my problems, thank you so much. but I have another question for you. How Can I make dynamic the time needed to call the function back? For example now the function  is called back every 5min. I would like to have this time randomly changable every time the function is called back.

Comment: Yes it works for me to execute a method after every specific time period.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();

Runnable mRunnableTask = new Runnable()
{
     @Override 
     public void run() {
          doSomething();
          // this will repeat this task again at specified time interval
          mHandler.postDelayed(this, yourDesiredInterval);
     }
};

// Call this to start the task first time
mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnableTask, yourDesiredInterval);
```

Don't forget to remove the callbacks from handler when you no longer need it.

Answer (score 0):

The latest and the most efficient way to perform this, even if you come out of the activitiy or close the app is to implement the `WorkManager` from the AndroidX Architecture.

You can find more details here from the official documentation: [Schedule tasks with WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)